# Postgresql error after installation could not connect to server

Tags: server, 16.10, postgresql

I get

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Tried to uninstall and reinstall, but no luck

Comment: Follow [this gorails guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) (scroll to bottom)

Comment: still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.(your_version_here)/

sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/9.(your_version_here)/
```

You need to replace the `(your_version_here)` with your `psql` version (9.5 most probably).

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285080/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: still the same, no luck